# How to rectify CSS flex issues appearing in MS Edge?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, microsoft-edge

On my online shop page, the 8 main product categories as well as the products below are displayed as tiles/boxes. The CSS has been optimized for and works great in my installed Chrome (version 79.0.3945.79) as well as my installed Safari (version 13.0.3) browser. However, the shop pages are completely messed up when viewed in Microsoft EDGE (version: 17.17134).

I tried to change the tile element's CSS but this destroys the appearance in Chrome etc. But as I have a limited knowledge of in flexbox, I am not entirely sure where to start.

I am looking for 
1) the CSS selector causing the error, and 
2) a way to address this error in MS Edge without changing the Chrome CSS settings.

My suspicion is that the following is causing the issue:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:850px)
.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item, .large-columns-4 > .col, .large-columns-4 .flickity-slider > .col {
    max-width: 25%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

The website shop page can be found [here](https://www.zweiterfruehling.net/shop/). I am grateful for any helpful tipps and ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further trial and error, I found the issue. The error was mitigated by changing the tile's parent element CSS from 
`display: flex;`
to
`display: inline-flex;`

This appears to work fine in all browsers, across MS Edge, Chrome etc.